# Perl: Correct way to use Sub-routine Prototypes  [%@$]

Tags: perl, parameter-passing

```
sub Function(\[$@%]);
```

This **works** on Windows (Perl v5.14.2 on Windows 7), and accepts all 3 kinds of arguments. Hashes, Scalars and Lists.

However, the same prototype on Linux (Perl 5.6.1 on CentOS release 4.5)  gives me

```
Malformed prototype for main::Function: \[%@$].
```

**On both, I am doing `use 5.006`.**
And otherwise, the scripts are exactly identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That prototype didn't exist back in 5.6.1. It's a recent addition as it was added in 5.14. (That means it's in all supported versions of Perl.)

You can't pass an array or a hash to a sub, only a list of scalars. The prototype is causing the calling code to take a reference and pass that. That's something you can do explicitly by changing

```
sub Function(\[$@%]) { }
Function($s);
Function(@a);
Function(%h);
```

to

```
sub Function { }
Function(\$s)
Function(\@a)
Function(\%h)
```

Prototypes are generally to be avoided anyway.

Comment: When I perform `use 5.006`, am I not forcing Perl 5.6 behaviour in windows as well?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon, No. You're specifying you want v5.6 or newer. It would turn off *features* (as in `use features`) you previously turned on but weren't present in 5.6.

Comment: Ahh... I misunderstood that `use` then. Was there any way to do this in Perl 5.6.1

Comment: I need to force it to give me a reference inside, when not passed a reference, which is why I was using `sub Function(\[$@%])`. No way at all to still do
`Function($s);, Function(%h);`?

Comment: Yes, use the `\[$@%]` prototype. You can't pass an array or a hash to a sub. Only a list of scalars, so you need to have Perl convert the arg into a reference before the sub is called, and that's what the prototype does.

Comment: Unfortunately no equivalent of `\[$@%]` for perl 5.6.1. So I can't take all 3 in in one function anymore as I need it to work on perl 5.6.1

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon, not unless the caller pass a ref like I showed. I would recommend avoiding the prototype even if it was available.